# Airflow: how to use dag_run argument value as trigger_rule in PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

I am trying to pass the trigger_rule of a PythonOperator via the config when triggering my DAG.
For example: `{"trigger_rule": "all_done"}`.
In other words, I want to be able to at runtime choose which trigger_rule to use by using the config when triggering the DAG.

However, it seems that the trigger_rule field in the PythonOperator is not a templated field. I.e. I can not implement it as follows:

```
PythonOperator(
   task_id='test',
   python_callable=my_func,
   trigger_rule="{{ dag_run.conf.get('trigger_rule', 'all_success') }}"
)
```

Any clues on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What is your airflow version?

Comment: we are using version 2.3.2

Comment: There are a few options, I would recommend looking [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) and searching for branch tasks and group tasks it might help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as `trigger_rule` is a parameter needed by the Scheduler to determine if a task should run; meaning it needs to be present *prior to* task runtime. Template fields are evaluated/rendered during task execution.

In essence, if a parameter is needed for the Scheduler it cannot be templated.